# Matrix invertible or not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given the matrix $A\in M_3(\mathbb{Z_6})$

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    5 & 3 & 3 \\
    1 & 4 & 1 \\
    3 & 5 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Is it invertible?

$det(A)=4$ but $4$ is not invertible in $\mathbb{Z_6}$ so the matrix is not invertible, right?

Comment: Right. A square matrix over $\;\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z\;$ is invertible iff its determinant equals $\;\pm1\pmod6\;$

Answer (score 3):

The matrix is not invertible, if it had an inverse say $B$ we would have $1=\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)=4\det(B)$ which is impossible in $\mathbb Z_6$